# Convert row's values to columns, keeping other columns as is

Tags: sql, sql-server, rows, procedure

I have following table :

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
abc      2      54      2016    qqq
xyz      3     2234     2015    ddd
```

and want the output as:

```
NewCol  abc xyz  Col4   Col5
Col2    2   3    2016   qqq
Col3    54  2234 2015   ddd
```

Can someone help on this with required query.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Add a few more rows with sample data, and adjust the result.

Comment: 1) Which database/version are you using? 2) Are there only 2 rows? What if there are multiple rows in your table, what would be expected output then?

Comment: i am using MS SQL 2014. Yes there are only two rows